# Tinymce image_class_list not working

Tags: javascript, css, html, tinymce-4

I'm trying to initialize tinymce with this options but I can't see the image class list in the image options. Don't know what is wrong with it.

My tinyMce version is 4.0

Here is the document for image class list http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:image_class_list

```
tinymce.init({
selector: "textarea",
theme: "modern",
height : 300,
    entity_encoding : "raw",
    remove_linebreaks : true,
    apply_source_formatting : false,
    force_p_newlines : false,
    cleanup : true,
plugins: [
    "coreimage advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
    "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
    "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
    "emoticons template paste textcolor"
],

templates : [
    {
            title: "2 Column 3-1 ve 3-2",
            url: "/adm/tpl/tools/tinymce/bootstrap_colums_3_1_3_2.html",
            description: "Column Templates"
    },
    {
            title: "2 Column 3-2 ve 3-1",
            url: "/adm/tpl/tools/tinymce/bootstrap_colums_3_2_3_1.html?22",
            description: "Column Templates"
    }

],


toolbar1: "template,|,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,alignleft,aligncenter,alignright,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
toolbar2: "cut,copy,paste,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,undo,redo,charmap,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,fullscreen,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,pagebreak,restoredraft",
toolbar3: "link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor,table",
image_advtab: true,
content_css : "/css/bootstrap.min.css",
image_list : <?php include "myexternallist.php"; ?>,

image_class_list: [
    {title: 'None', value: ''},
    {title: 'Image Responsive', value: 'img-responsive'},
    {title: 'Image Circle', value: 'img-circle'},
    {title: 'Image Rounded', value: 'img-rounded'},
    {title: 'Image Thumbnail', value: 'img-thumbnail'}
]
```

});

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem. It was the version of the tinyMce. I updated the script from 4 to 4.1.9 and problem solved.